# Changing version of a web view using Clearcase rcleartool

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I'm using the rcleartool version that comes with Clearteam Explorer 8.0.0 
Running rcleartool -ver gives:
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\IMShared\plugins\com.ibm.rational.ccrc.cli_8.0.0.v20140305_0215
I can't change my Clearteam Explorer version, but could use a different rcleartool version if it would work.

**I want to be able to update my entire Web view to a chosen label or version from the command-line.**

I see that "update -add" allows you to change the load rules, but as far as I can tell doesn't let you change the version selection rules?

"get" does let you specify a version or label but as far as I can see can only be used on a single file?

Is it possible to do what I want to do using rcleartool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CCRC (ClearCase Remote Client) API rcleartool](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021929) (which [can be installed here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21598728)) can allow you to edit a config spec.

Even though setcs isn't listed, you can try it, but [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?crawler=1&uid=swg1PI11015) mentions "ClearTeam Explorer command line `rcleartool setcs` does not fill config spec as expected."

So the safest way remains to edit the config spec:

```
cd /path/to/your/web/view
rcleartool edcs
```

And all the config spec selection rule to view first your label (then the other rules)

If you are using UCM, the easiest way is to create a new project/integration stream, which you can then rebase to any baseline you want.
Or create a child stream to the stream where your label (baseline in UCM) has been created and rebase that baseline.

Comment: Thanks. It would be good if it was clearer what the problem was with setcs, it seems to work for simple cases I have tried.
However I'll stick with edcs and let the user change it manually.