# How to annotate a folder in cleartool

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I am trying to annotate a folder with command **cleartool annotate folderName**
getting error

> cleartool: Error: Unable to create file "test_tut_element_vob.ann": Permission denied.

I am able to annotate the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`cleartool annotate` man page](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_annotate.htm) mentions the following caveat:

> The `annotate` command extracts information from the element's versions.
>   To do so, it invokes the annotate method of the element's type manager.
>
> Only the `text_file_delta` and `z_text_file_delta` type managers (which correspond to the predefined element types `text_file` and `compressed_text_file`) include an annotate method.
>   **You must use the `-ndata` option when annotating versions of other element types.**

So check the type manager associated with `test_tut_element_vob.ann`.

if "`-ndata`" does not work, depending on the nature of the content of `test_tut_element_vob.ann`, you can change its type. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25482976/6309) for `compressed_file`.

---

> it is my vob name and i am trying to annotate the whole vob

`cleartool annotate` lists the contents of a version, annotating each line to indicate when, and in which version, the line was added.
This is to be used on a file element, not on a vob.

If the goal is to annotate all files within a vob, then you need a view and you can find all files, in order to use annotate:

Unix:

```
cd /path/to/view/vobs/test_tut_element_vob.ann
cleartool find . -type f -exec 'cleartool annotate "$CLEARCASE_PN"'
```

Windows:

```
cd c:\path\to\view\test_tut_element_vob.ann
cleartool find . -type f -exec "cleartool annotate \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
```

Comment: i am using the -nData and getting this error stated in question.

Comment: @akshayjain why -nData? why not -ndata? (just in case it is case sensitive)

Comment: @akshayjain check the properties of your file (not of your version of the file, of the file element itself): http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146356

Comment: In type manager tab use type manager`s merge method is selected.

Comment: @akshayjain what do you see in the Supertype field of that same "type manager" tab?

Comment: i am seeing the type manager of file file_system_object and it has nothing in Supertype field it is non editable and some other files have file_system_object in that field.

Comment: @akshayjain As in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146566, what is the output of `cleartool describe test_tut_element_vob.ann`? If `test_tut_element_vob.ann` is a text file, can you change its type to `text_file` (`cleartool chtype text_file test_tut_element_vob.ann`), and try `annotate` then?

Comment: 'cleartool: Error: Unable to access "test_tut_element_vob.ann": No such file or directory.' on the command _'cleartool describe test_tut_element_vob.ann'_

Comment: @akshayjain are you executing that command in the folder where `test_tut_element_vob.ann` is?

Comment: this file does not created because whlie annotating this folder named test_tut_element_vob with the command **cleartool -ndata folder name** giving me error.Is it possible to annotate the whole folder in cleratool??

Comment: @akshayjain I don't understand: cleartool annotate is for file already in source control, not for private generated files. Is `test_tut_element_vob.ann` a file already added to source control in ClearCase or not?

Comment: it is my vob name and i am trying to annotate the whole vob

Comment: @akshayjain What? No! `cleartool annotate` is to be used on a file. To used it on a vob content, see my edited answer.